# ¿Como agregar un objeto a un arreglo sin que se modifiquen los demás objetos?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un arreglo y un objeto que contiene modelos.

Quiero agregar el objeto al arreglo con la función `push()`, pero al hacerlo cambia todos los valores existente en el arreglo haciendo referencia al objeto.

***Ejemplo de mi código***

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      dato: {
        nombre: '',
        apellido: ''
      },
      array: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.array.push(this.dato)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" v-model="dato.nombre" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" v-model="dato.apellido" />
  <button v-on:click="add">PUSH</button>
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in array">
      {{ n }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

> Sería genial que alguien sepa como hacer que el arreglo sea `estático`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías simplemente `copiar` el objeto y guarda la copia en el arreglo.

Para esto podrías usar [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign)

### Demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      dato: {
        nombre: '',
        apellido: ''
      },
      array: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      // AQUI creamos una copia
      var copia = Object.assign({}, this.dato);
      this.array.push(copia)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" v-model="dato.nombre" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" v-model="dato.apellido" />
  <button v-on:click="add">PUSH</button>
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in array">
      {{ n }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Saludos.